# Keep two canvases side by side with changing aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, canvas, alignment

I am attempting to display two canvases side by side on Chrome (gameScreen on the left, scoreScreen on the right). I would like these canvases to remain side by side regardless of the screen size/aspect ratio. Below is my HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="scoreScreen" width="300" height="600"> </canvas>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#gameScreen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/* #scoreScreen {
            border: 1px solid black;
          } */

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This works for a 1024x600 sized screen, but as the screen size gets bigger and bigger the left canvas (game screen) starts to overlap with the right canvas. I tried to wrap both canvases with a div tag and assigned the div tag a relative location, however, I was unable to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tag parent *flexibility* rule `<canvas>`. Add `display: flex` and rule `gap` for omission to the `<body>` tag.

`<canvas>` tags will always be *side-by-side* regardless of screen size.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    /*display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;*/
    display: flex;
    gap: 8px;
}

#gameScreen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#scoreScreen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="scoreScreen" width="300" height="600"> </canvas>
</body>
```